# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.Expanded'

Tags: android, parent, statusbar, android-styles

I am trying to make theme for CM engine. And I have added some assets but when I try to change clock color in notifications panel, eclipse gives me this:

```
assets/overlays/com.android.systemui/res/values/styles.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.Expanded'.
assets/overlays/com.android.systemui/res/values/styles.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.Expanded'.
```

And this is **styles.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="TextAppearance.StatusBar.Expanded.Clock" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.Expanded">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffD4AF37</item>
    </style>
    <style name="TextAppearance.StatusBar.Expanded.Date" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.Expanded">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffD4AF37</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: You have forgotten to ask solution?

Comment: Yep, my bad.
So anyone know how to "repair" that ?

Answer (score 0):

StatusBar styles are for API 9 onwards.

Useful links are;

[Android.com Applying Styles and Themes, Using Platform Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles)

[Android.com R.style reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html)

[Android.com Android API levels](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html)